# Is Salah of men prayed with tight pants and jeans accepted?

Tags: salat, fiqh, clothing, awrah

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidil-Mursalin wa 'ala 'Alihi wa Sahbihi Ajma'in.

---

One of the conditions for Salah is covering one's Awrah. **Is Salah of men prayed with tight pants and jeans accepted?**

**With other words, are tight pants and jeans considered to cover Awrah?**

*Please, answer with proof from Qur'an and Sunnah.*

Answer (score 1):

It is makrooh to wear tight clothing generally for male and females. You can pray in tight clothing however it is best not to, and the clothing should be in between being too tight and too loose so in between that.- IslamQA

To wear such tight fitting trousers, which reveal the shape of the private area in salah, is Makruh and against the etiquette of salah.

Allah subḥānahu wa ta'āla (glorified and exalted be He) in the Holy Qur’an says,

“O Children of Adam! Take your adornment during every prayer.” (Surah Al-Aaraf v.31)

To conclude wearing tight clothing is makrooh and wearing transparent clothing is not allowed as you will be able to see the skin underneath the clothing. In salah time it would be better to wear loose clothing or wear something like a thoub/jubbah or a shalwar kamise

Comment: Is Salah prayed with tight pants and jeans accepted?

Comment: It’s is makhrooh